# GA for Firebase | In which step of the funnel use "present_offer" event

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm implementing GA for Firebase data collection for an eCommerce mobile app.

In its [implementation guidelines](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317498?hl=en), Firebase recommends using "present_offer" event to track promotion impressions of a product.

However, I don't know when I must fire this event? Should I implement it within the product detail page when an offer is available (e.g.: 20% discount on a t-shirt) or during the checkout process as many times as product promotions recorded in the user cart?

There is no details about when this tag must be fired this is the reason why your help will be very appreciated.

Thnaks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the additional documentation on the [`PRESENT_OFFER` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event):

> Present Offer event.
>
> This event signifies that the app has presented a purchase offer to a user. Add this event to a funnel with the `ADD_TO_CART` and `ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE` to gauge your conversion process.
>
> Note: If you supply the VALUE parameter, you must also supply the CURRENCY parameter so that revenue metrics can be computed accurately.

It reads to me like you should log this event when you first show the offer to the user. In your case that would be in the offer detail page as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your help. It's crystal clear.